# Convert nasted javascript object to array - Vuetify dropdown

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm trying to convert and fill dropdown with values from object, but its not working correctly.

Backend is Express.js with Sequelize, where I'm calling some MySQL procedure.

Here is short `console.log` of returned object: `(4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, __ob__: Observer]`, and it looks like this on browser: `[{"dropdown_value":"2000"},{"dropdown_value":"2002"},{"dropdown_value":"2012"},{"dropdown_value":"2017"}]`

I'm trying to use this data for dropdown vuetify input like this:

```
created() {
  this.$vuetify.theme.dark = false
  this.getDropdownData()
},
data: () => ({
  drawer: null,
  dropdownValues: [],
  /* eslint-disable */
  alignmentz: 'start',
  dense: false,
  justifyz: "end",
}),
methods: {

  async getDropdownData() {

     try {
       this.dropdownValues = (await DataService.getDropdownData()).data
      // this.dropdownValues = new Array("Ivan", "Marko")
       console.log(this.dropdownValues)
     } catch (error) {

       console.log(error)
     }
  },

}
```

And vuetify code:

```
<v-col cols="12" lg="2" md="2" sm="6" xs="6">

        <v-select


        :items="dropdownValues"
        item-text="state"
        item-value="abbr"
        label="Select"
        persistent-hint
        return-object
        single-line

      ></v-select>

    </v-col>
```

When I click on dropdown I got [Object object] and also, vue warning where vuetify elements expect to use Array, **not** object!

I tried to convert it on backend, but it's not working correctly. 
When I uncomment this line: `// this.dropdownValues = new Array("Ivan", "Marko")`, its working fine. 
Is there I'm missing something ?

Comment: this.dropdownValues = arr.map(o => o.dropdown_value) you can do like this

Comment: or `item-text="dropdown_value"` if you look at the docs (look like you got your example from there) you'll notice state and abbr are keys in the list of objects. Your object keys are different

Comment: @depperm OMG! That was so easy. Thank you really, wasted 2 hours here.